# Excel pivot ghost field

Tags: excel, pivot

I have a field in a pivot table that I don't know where is the data feeding from. As you see in the picture I have a table with the field 'EMEA/NonEMEA', but I don't have a field called 'EMEA/NonEMEA2'. There are no formulas in the pivot either and no hidden columns in the table. I don't know what else to check.

Any ideas how this field might have been created?

[image]

Comment: Sounds silly, but have you checked *each* header row in your Table? IIRC, when you create a new column in a table and don't name it, it may inherit the name from a column nearby and add "2"?

Comment: I did check each header and there is no other column named as EMEA/NonEMEA, blank or hidden. If I refresh the table the field 2 doesn't disapear, so somehow this field2 has been created somehow (there are no formulas thought). If I select the same table and create a pivot the field 2 does not appear. I'm a bit puzzled.

Comment: Just make some break through. I selected the field2 and pressed 'ungroup' and made the field disappear. If I select 'EMEA/NonEMEA' and press 'Group Selection' it create the field2. What I don't see is how the groups have been created. Where can I see how the grouping has been designed?